# Why doesn't my value get updated in gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, updating

I have a gridview where if I click update, I will be able to update the number of fabric issued by clicking a value on the drop down list. However when I click update and check back the values are still the same as before. Please help!

**My update method in the class PPFabric**

```
    public int update()
    {
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                        ["ZZFashionIMSConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ProductionPlanFabric SET PPFabricIssued = @FStock WHERE ProductionPlanID = @ProductionPlanID AND FashionStyleID = @FashionStyleID AND FabricID = @FabricID", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FStock", PPFabricIssued);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productionplanid", ProductionPlanID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fashionstyleid", FashionStyleID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fabricid", FabricID);

        conn.Open();
        int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        if (count != 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return -2;
    }
```

**Update button code in IssueFabric webform**

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            PPFabric objPPFabric = new PPFabric();
            objPPFabric.PPFabricIssued = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFabricIssued.SelectedValue);

            int errorCode = objPPFabric.update();

            if (errorCode == 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Fabric details has been updated successfully!";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else if (errorCode == -2)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Unable to update edited record as it was not found!";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }

        }
    }
```

**Datasource in view pending fabric page**

```
    private void displayPendingFabric()
    {
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                         ["ZZFashionIMSConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductionPlanID, FashionStyleID, FabricID, WarehouseID, PPStatus, PPFabricReqd, PPFabricIssued FROM ProductionPlanFabric WHERE PPStatus = 0 OR PPStatus = 2", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter daPPFabric = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet result = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        daPPFabric.Fill(result, "ProductionPlanFabric");
        DataView dvPPFabric = result.Tables["ProductionPlanFabric"].DefaultView;
        //dvPPFabric.Sort = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
        conn.Close();

        gvPPFabric.DataSource = dvPPFabric;
        gvPPFabric.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Where/How do you define the DataSource for the GridView?

Comment: Hi! I've edited and added in my codes. Do take a look and advise. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I can see in your code tells the program to refresh the gridview.  You could do one of two things:

1. Call *displayPendingFabric()* if your update was successful *if (errorCode == 0)*
2. Add an event handler for the *SqlDataAdapter RowUpdated* event where you could call your *displayPendingFabric()* method or refresh the GridView:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated(v=vs.110).aspx